# Why is the formal parameter unable to be operated? Like the actual parameter. See the below example

Tags: javascript

```
// Declare a function where the formal parameter executes some operation.
// It will display the error "Unexpected token ++".
function log(num++) {
    return num;
}

// Declare a normal function.
function logNormal(num) {
    return num;
}

// Calls the logNormal function, and the parameter deliverd will execute some operation.
var a = 5;
logNormal(a++); // 5
logNormal(a); // 6
logNormal(++a); // 7
```

Now the question here, why can't the formal parameter execute operation?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would ever want to do that. you could just do `return ++num` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** This is simply not included in the ECMAStandard grammar specification.

**Long answer:**

Why do you ever want to do this?

There are two 'solutions' for your problem:

```
function log() {
    num++;
    return num;
}

function log2() {
    return ++num;
}
```

Parameter lists should only contain the declaration of parameters (and possibly their default values). No more, no less in my opinion.